# Specific vue mixin function doesn't get executed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I am using Vue.js with global functions which I have definied under Vue `mixin`. In my component I call different functions from this Vue `mixin`. However, whenever I try to call `checkUser` which only contains a `console.log(...)` line nothing happens. Not even the line gets printed in the console.

But I am wondering, why other functions of this `mixin`, e.g. `handleSubmit` get called and executed without any problems at all from the same component. Even in the same function.... I even tried to rename the function, doesn't work.. It's also not a cache problem because other changes on the `mixin` work and I refresh the `app.js` file in my browser and can see the changes...

My goal is to check if the user is logged in and if not to show an error message. So, the `checkUser` function needs to be called before the `axios` request is being made and the `axios` request needs to wait till the `checkUser` function has returned either `true` or `false`. I know that I need a `if-statement` for that, however, first I would like to figure out why my function is now getting called...?

Here is my sourcecode. If you need more let me know...
app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();

Vue.component('products-list-view', require('./components/ProductListView.vue').default);

//Vue mixin
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        handleSubmitError(error){
            if(error.response.status == 403){
                // Show not logged in modal
                //EventBus.$emit('user-not-logged-in-show-modal');
            }else if(error.response.status != 422){
                window.toastr.error('Es gab einen Fehler', 'Es gab einen ungewöhnlichen Fehler, bitte probiere es später noch einmal!');
            }
        },
        formatPrice(value, decimals){
            let val = (value/1).toFixed(decimals).replace('.', ',');
            return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");
        },
        checkUser(user){
            console.log('TEST??!!')
        }
    }
});

window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Component

```
<template>
    <div @click="toogleProductMark">
        <p>Toogle Product Mark</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "ProductListView",
        methods: {
            toogleProductMark(){
                this.checkUser(true); // <-- WHY is this line not getting executed?

                if(this.product.isMarkedAuthUser){
                    axios.post(this.product.actions.unmark.route, {value: 1})
                        .then((r) => {
                            this.product.isMarkedAuthUser = false;
                        }).catch((e) => {
                        this.handleSubmitError(e); // <-- BUT this does?
                    });
                }else if(!this.product.isMarkedAuthUser){
                    axios.post(this.product.actions.mark.route, {value: 1})
                        .then((r) => {
                            this.product.isMarkedAuthUser = true;
                        }).catch((e) => {
                        this.handleSubmitError(e); // <-- AND this as well?
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: How do I do this and why does `handleSubmitError` works then?

Comment: Here it is also working like I have implemented it: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/LWRVGQ?editors=1010

Comment: Here you can also see that it works globally without defining it for every component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin